# ffmpeg output mkv displays duration of 00:00 in vlc

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the -ss and -t flags on a video to break it into chunks, but I can't seem to get it to split and include clip duration for mkv.

How do I get ffmpeg to write the correct timestamp on the output file?

Below is the commandline I am using:

```
ffmpeg -i "HDHomerun-record01.mpg" -vf yadif -sws_flags lanczos -s hd720 -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -acodec copy -avoid_negative_ts 1 -preset slower -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:17:24 "HDHomerun-record01-0.mkv"
```

Comment: Thanks for the command, but please include the *output* as well. The whole thing starting with `ffmpeg version…` up to the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into this problem, what solved it for me was simply updating to ffmpeg 2.1-2 (I am on arch linux)